# Positioning Balloon ToolTips over TreeNodes

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, tooltip

I want to add a `ToolTip` to `TreeView` nodes and make a balloon appear at the mouse coordinates:

```
private void treeView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    node = treeView1.getNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
    toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
    toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;
    toolTip1.InitialDelay = 500;
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(treeView1, node.Text);
}
```

The problem is that the `ToolTip` is assigned to the `TreeView`, not to the `TreeNode`, and the position of the balloon is quite strange - not at the expected mouse coordinates, but somewhere in `treeView1`.

I was trying to use `toolTip1.Show()` but the `InitialDelay` property is ignored.

How can I position a balloon `ToolTip` over a `TreeNode` and delay its display?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ToolTip` control is not necessary in order to display tooltips for the `TreeNodes`. The `TreeView` has a property `ShowNodeToolTips` that you can set to `true` and the `TreeNodes` have a `ToolTipText` property.

---

However, if you want to display the `ToolTip` as a balloon, things get more complicated. Fortunately the `TreeView` has a `NodeMouseHover` event. Together with a `Timer`, we can make our `ToolTip` behave as expected.

In our form, we make these declarations and set the timer event handler

```
private const int InitialToolTipDelay = 500, MaxToolTipDisplayTime = 2000;

private ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private TreeNode toolTipNode;

public frmTreeViewWithToolTip()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    toolTip.IsBalloon = true;
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
}
```

In `NodeMouseHover` we initiate the process

```
private void treeView_NodeMouseHover(object sender,
                                     TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    toolTip.Hide(this);

    toolTipNode = e.Node;

    timer.Interval = InitialToolTipDelay;
    timer.Start();
}
```

The timer will be started twice: once for the initial delay and once for maximum display time of the balloon. Therefore we must handle these two cases in the `timer.Tick` event handler

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    if (timer.Interval == InitialToolTipDelay) { 
        Point mousePos = treeView.PointToClient(MousePosition);

        // Show the ToolTip if the mouse is still over the same node.
        if (toolTipNode.Bounds.Contains(mousePos)) {
             // Node location in treeView coordinates.
            Point loc = toolTipNode.Bounds.Location;

             // Node location in form client coordinates.
            loc.Offset(treeView.Location);

            // Make balloon point to upper right corner of the node.
            loc.Offset(toolTipNode.Bounds.Width - 7, -12);

            toolTip.Show("Node: " + toolTipNode.Text, this, loc);

            timer.Interval = MaxToolTipDisplayTime;
            timer.Start();
        }
    } else {
        // Maximium ToolTip display time exceeded.
        toolTip.Hide(this);
    }
}
```

Finally, we do not want to display the `ToolTip` if the mouse leaves the `TreeView`

```
private void treeView_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    toolTip.Hide(this);
}
```

Comment: it works great, I have one more question is there any chance to customize the appearence of this toolTip (to balloon like). Thanks for answer.

Comment: My initial answer was only useful if standard tooltips were required. I added and tested a solution, which creates balloon tooltips, delays them in an appropriate manner and displays them at a convenient position relative to the concerned `TreeNode`.

Comment: Have a look at the properties of the `ToolTip`. You can change its color, change the font, set a title and a icon and more. If you set the property `OwnerDraw` to `true` you can draw the `ToolTip` yourself in a `ToolTip.Draw` event handler (works only if `IsBalloon == false`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use:

toolTip1.Show("text", treeView1, point);